# How to get count of all elements which are in dropdown list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dropdown list like

```
 <select id="ddlProjects">
   <option value="315">resproject</option>
   <option value="320" style-"display:inline">newheavn</option>
   <option value="395" style="display:inline">cealon sales</option>
   <option value="395" style="display:inline">cealon sales</option>
 </select>
```

Now , I want count of all elements which are "display:inline"  on change, how can i get it.

Comment: SideNote: A typo in line `style-"display:inline"`

Comment: Might help you http://jsfiddle.net/9SMZD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute selector in jquery to get length of the options in dropdownlist

```
    $('#ddlProjects').change(function(){
    var len = $(this).find('option[style="display:inline"]').length
    console.log(len)
   });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NSg8c/2/)

Answer (score 1):

By default the `display` property of `<option>` is set to `inline`

If you still need to filter according to this property, use this,

```
$('#ddlProjects').change(function(){
    var count = $('option',this).filter(function(){
        var css =$(this).attr('style');
        return css !=undefined && css.indexOf('display:inline')>-1;
    }).length;
    console.log(count);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eQg85/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try to use `.filter()` at this context,</s>

```
$('#ddlProjects').change(function(){
  var count = $(this).children().filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('display') === "inline" 
  }).length;
  console.log(count);
})
```

Try to use `attribute contains selector` at this situation, since the default display property of an option element is inline.

```
$('#ddlProjects').change(function(){
    var count = $('option[style*="display:inline"]',this).length;
    console.log(count);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gUEEt/)

Comment: This won't work as the default `display` of an `option` is `inline`. It will always return the total number of option elements, unless they are hidden.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, you're right, facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ddlProjects option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('display') === 'inline';
}).length;
```

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answer a bit more. Just posting a code block without any explanation or context is not good. In its current state your answer might not be of any use to people looking for an answer to this question in the future.